# Getting Facebook publish_actions Permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, publish-actions

If this is the wrong place to ask this - I super apologize in advance, I'm at a loss here.

I'm trying to develop a simple Facebook PHP app and I'm having trouble getting publish_actions. Here's how the app will work:

1. You enter your email address
2. Periodically, you receive emails like this ("Hey nice person, here's a video we think you might be interested in, click here to share it on your wall")
3. You click the button, it takes you to the app site, which asks for your publish permissions
4. You enter a message and share the video to your wall.

My problem: all of that requires publish_actions permissions, but FB won't grant them to me until I can show a working app (I applied for permissions and was denied because "Canvas
Your app isn't loading properly and errors appeared while testing your app").

My question: How do I get access to publish_actions without being able to show a working app (which requires publish_actions)? Can I use PHP to post to my own wall in development mode somehow to test it out?

Again - I apologize for the dumbness of this question, I am a PHP dev who is very new to FB, and I've looked everywhere for answers on this.

Comment: You can use your FB account in development mode to do anything, but the post which you've shared will not be shown for your friends. If you want your friends can read what you've shared, you much complete your app and submit to FB to reviewed

Comment: I cant use "publish_actions" with developer account either. Is there another configuration needed in FB console?

Comment: I have the same problem. Are there any solutions for this ? I even tried to explain 10 times the problem to Facebook support but they do not listen.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Facebook Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

You will be able to simulate some of the app permissions as if it was production.

Just go and select your app, then select Get User Access Token, finally select all the permissions you want to test.

Use the given token to develop and test things out and when you have a semi finished version, submit it through the app review section, following the [Facebook App Review Guidelines](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review)

I submitted screenshots, a video of my app working, and step by step description on how to reproduce the publish action.

Hope it helps.